# How can I find used lib version in Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, androidx

For an example, I want to find out, if at all androidx libraries were used, and if yes, what version?

- androidx.activity
- androidx.fragment
- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions

I know how to look up in the build.gradle files. But I also want to know, if these libraries, are imported indirectly by another library, without being listed in my gradle files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using gradle you can see the complete dependency list of your project by running the following command in the project root directory :

```
./gradlew app:androidDependencies
```

or this if you want to see them as a **tree**

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

You can also see the list in Android Studio, as described in the [View module dependency](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#view-dependency-tree) docs, by selecting **View** -> **Tool Windows** -> **Gradle**